# Looking for a regex for a password with at least one lowercase letter, at least one upper case letter, at least one digit & length between 6 and 14

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression for a validating a password.  The password rules are:

- at least one lowercase letter
- at least one upper case letter
- at least one digit
- length between 6 and 14

I created following regular expression but it's not working

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,14}$
```

It's accepting

- qwerty1
- QWERTY1

  but not qwERTy

i.e. it's fulfilling only 2 conditions

- at least one digit
- length between 6 and 14

Comment: what do you mean by not working? if it is giving error.. share the error.. if it is failing for a case.. share the sample :)

Comment: Are you using any particular languages to achieve this or just regex?

Comment: I need this regular expression for client side validation @npinti

Comment: Regex is working properly.. there might be some other issue with validation logic.. see https://regex101.com/r/kW8qS1/2

Comment: What you are after can be achieved with things other than regular expressions. If you are using JavaScript, you could take a look at something similar to @Amit's solution. A regular expression might be too obscure and/or difficult to maintain/understand.

Comment: Ohh that works.Thanks. However,I forgot to mention one more condition. How to restrict spaces here? Passwords shouldn't hold any white space also. So I need to restrict '/s' as well. Can you help in achieving this @karthikmanchala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\S` instead of `.` for restricting spaces:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\S{6,14}$
                                ^
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kW8qS1/4)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that's possible, but I'm sure that if it is, and it turns out a long complicated regex string, it's a wrong design decision. It will be unmaintainable, unclear and very error prone.

At the same time, this is easy to do, understand and maintain:

```js
function isValid(password)
{
  if(password.length < 6 || password.length > 14)
    return false;

  var valid = { hasLower: false, hasUpper: false, hasDigit: false };
  for(var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
    var c = password[i];
    var upperC = c.toUpperCase();
    valid.hasLower |= c != upperC;
    valid.hasUpper |= c == upperC;
    valid.hasDigit |= c >= '0' && c <= '9';
  }

  return valid.hasLower && valid.hasUpper && valid.hasDigit;
}

alert('"123abcDEF" valid = ' + isValid('123abcDEF'));
alert('"123  DEF" valid = ' + isValid('123  DEF'));
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does "|=" mean?  @Amit

Comment: Its a [bitwise or assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_OR_assignment)